# Cannot get a FlowLayoutPanel to Expand

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a FlowLayoutPanel, and I am constantly adding controls to it. They all work, yeah, life is wonderful.

But when the container hits its boundaries, it just stays the same size. Now, I realize I can make it have scrollbars, but this is not what I desire. I want the FlowLayoutPanel to grow in size based on the controls added. Any ideas?

I have AutoSize mode set to true, by the way. This doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a `FlowLayoutPanel` to a `Form`. I added a button with the following `Click` handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button());
}
```

On the FLP, I set `FlowDirection` to `TopDown` and `AutoSize` to `true`. I also set the `BorderStyle` to `FixedSingle` to see what's happening.

Now when you run this and click the button, it'll add other buttons to the FLP. When you add too many, the form hides the overflowing-FLP.

I'm not sure if this is what you're after, but if you want the `Form` to increase in size as well, you set `AutoSize` to `true` on the `Form` too.

If this isn't what you're looking for, please provide more details.

Comment: I want the FLP to keep growing, instead of hiding new controls. I don't care about the form.

Comment: @Stacey - Not setting `AutoSize` on the `Form` allows the FLP to keep growing. Try creating a new project to test what I wrote out; it works for me.